# Make HTML table-row snap to height of largest image in table-cell

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvqdrwp9/3/

I want the images (which could be any size), to stretch the height of all the adjacent table-cells to match. There will only be 2 rows, with 2 cells each. One cell contains an image, the other text. I want the text cells to match the height of the adjacent image. I have overflow:hidden on the cells, so image overflowing horizontally is not an issue.

The text in boxes 2 and 3 should be vertically aligned in the middle, and the rows should be dictated by the heights of the images in boxes (cells) 1 and 4.

I can't understand why I am still getting a red line at the bottom of each image.

```css
.about-boxes {
  display: table;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.about-box-row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.about-box {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.about-box img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.about-box-1,
.about-box-4 {
  background: red;
}
.about-box-2,
.about-box-3 {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-boxes">
  <div class="about-box-row">
    <div class="about-box about-box-1">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x180/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="about-box about-box-2">
      <h2>Text</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis velit repellat voluptate eum est re- iciendis eius recusandae molestiae iusto, dolor quis- quam voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-box-row">
    <div class="about-box about-box-3">
      <h2>Text</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisic- ing elit. Perspiciatis velit repellat voluptate eum est reiciendis eius recusandae molestiae iusto, dolor quisquam voluptas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-box about-box-4">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320x360/000/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should add, its the vertical padding i have a problem with, normally the max-width on the table would be about 600px

Comment: If you inspect your elements in chrome, you'll see that the vertical alignment of your images is off and getting cropped by overflow.

Comment: cropped by overflow? explain what you mean sorry... I thought putting height:100%; and width:auto; on the image, and then overflow:hidden on the container cell would make the container cell be the height of the image and hide any overflow horizontally... it does that, but with a thin red line at the bottom.

could you post an answer with code snippet?

Comment: Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.about-box img { ...`,  to get rid of the incorrect alignment of images.

Comment: Try adding img { margin-top: 4px } to your css: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvqdrwp9/4/).  Cropped meaning that the overflow is hidden.  @DavidDomain has a better solution, however.

Comment: @DavidDomain exactly what I was missing - thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Posted an answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `display: block` or `vertical-align: middle` on the image to correct the alignment of it.

```
.about-box img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Or..

```
.about-box img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Both work.